# cvSaveImage and imwrite not working

Tags: xcode, opencv

I am using opencv on xcode (.mm file). I would like to save the IplImage into an image. I understand that .mm file is objective C++ extension and i need to use C++ opencv function. I have tried using both `cvSaveImage`(C) and `cv::imwrite` (C++), on both occasions, there is no error on both compile and run time. However,when i go to the folder as specified, the image is not created.

Here is how i declare the function.

I have tried with cvSaveImage initially.

```
IplImage Frame;
cvSaveImage("/Users/myname/Desktop/image.jpg", Frame);
```

The code does not work, so i try with imwrite.

```
cv::Mat mat_img(Frame,true);//converting iplimage to mat
imwrite("/Users/myname/Desktop/image.jpg", mat_img);
```

On both occasions, no image has been generated even after I have added the full path.

Any suggestion on what I have done wrong?

Thanks. Your advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you load an image in your program?

Comment: Downvoter should comment, the question does show research effort

Comment: please avoid opencv's deprecated c-api. it is no more a  valid option.

Comment: @ikleung1 Try with a simpler image type, like `.bmp`, it could be that your opencv library has not been built with jpg support (I would expect it to throw an exception, though... Are you by any chance intercepting exceptions somewhere?)

Comment: BTW, are you initializing `Frame`? I mean, is there some code between the variable declaration and `cvSaveImage`?

Comment: what's the return value of `cv::imwrite()`? and take care that only 8-bit (or 16-bit unsigned in case of PNG, JPEG 2000, and TIFF) single-channel or 3-channel (with ‘BGR’ channel order) images can be saved using this function.

Comment: @HaDang thanks for your reply and suggestion. I have tried to load an image with imread and cvLoadImage. I have declared iplImage* image and Mat image as null respectively but after calling the load function which is supposed to load an image of 640x640, the width and height remain 0.

Comment: @Antonio thank you for your encouragement and advice. I have tried to change the jpg format to .bmp by editing the extension, however, i am still unable to save or load the image. I am actually extracting the frame from AVcaptureoutput buffer and i have tried to directly save the image once i get the IplImage but to no success.

Comment: @berak thank you for your reply. I am currently using opencv 2.49, i know that some functions are being deprecated. Is there any other opencv approach that I can try besides the above so that i can save IplImage to png/jpg image? I am doing this for debugging purposes as I have to extract the eye portion of the image after that, so i would like to see the initial image and the sub-image.

Comment: please do not use IpImages in the 1st place, but cv::Mat.

Comment: @lkleung1: try this code example: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html

Comment: Maybe this is problem of permissions, i.e. the program just can't write to this directory. Try another one.

Comment: hi @Kornel i think you are right. The IplImage that i have created is 4 channel, thus it cannot be saved. Thanks a lot!